# Number input type validation bugged in IE11, possible pure JS workaround?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-11

The validation for number input types in IE11 is completely broken - the `ValidityState` object will always have `valid: true`, `patternMismatch: false` etc.

Irritatingly, the one area where it does function somewhat as intended is by keeping the value set to null if text is entered (although it will assign a value to text preceded by a number), so I'm unable to validate by using JS to check against that.

Consequently I have no idea how to check input validation as values are entered. The only solution I can think of is to validate against `keydown` events, but not only is that a fair bit of extra hassle, it doesn't cover edge cases like someone pasting text into the input.

Does anyone have any other suggestions before I give up? No jQuery please, pure JS only.

**Edit:** I'm already using the `input` event. The problem I have with that is IE doesn't assign invalid entries to the input's `value` property - consequently I can't check between an input with an invalid entry and one that's just empty.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `input` event, and add the `novalidate` attribute to your form, which disables browser validation:

```js
var counterEl = document.getElementById('changes');
var count = 0;

document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('input', function() {
  counterEl.innerHTML = count++;
});
```

```html
<form novalidate>
    <input type="text" id="input"/>
    <span id="changes"></span>
</form>
```

Alternatively you could use the `change` event, which doesn't fire as often.

Comment: I'm using the input event already; the problem is the input's value is left as empty if invalid characters are entered, so there's no way to distinguish between invalid input and no input.

Comment: @chrBrd You could use `novalidate`, added that to my answer

Comment: Good suggestion, and would probably work in a lot of cases. Just to be extra-annoying, however - this part of my validation's done as the inputs are entered, not when they're submitted. So sadly that won't work either.

Comment: Once again, something I'd considered, but it means losing the arrows and keyboard functionality of the number input type. I'm just going to skip validation on entry in IE...

Answer (score 0):

Use [`onInput`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oninput) instead of `keydown`:

> An event handler for the input event on the window. The input event is raised when an  element value changes.
>
> This event bubbles. If supported on the window, it is supported on  elements as well.

Meaning that it triggers when the user types, pastes something or blurs the field.

Comment: That's what I'm already using but the input's value is left as null if the entry is invalid, so I can't distinguish between an invalid input and and an empty one.